# How to clone array of hashes and add key value using each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, iteration

I want to clone an array of hashes and then to clone it into more than one.

```
irb(main):001:0> arr = [{a: "one", b: "two"}, {a: "uno", b: "due"}, {a: "en", b: "to"}]
=> [{:a=>"one", :b=>"two"}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due"}, {:a=>"en", :b=>"to"}]
irb(main):002:0> arr_1 = arr.clone
=> [{:a=>"one", :b=>"two"}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due"}, {:a=>"en", :b=>"to"}]
irb(main):003:0> arr_2 = arr.clone
=> [{:a=>"one", :b=>"two"}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due"}, {:a=>"en", :b=>"to"}]
```

Dynamically I want to add `id` into the hashes.

```
irb(main):004:0> arr_1.each { |k| k[:id] = 1 }
=> [{:a=>"one", :b=>"two", :id=>1}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due", :id=>1}, {:a=>"en", :b=>"to", :id=>1}]
irb(main):005:0> arr_2.each { |k| k[:id] = 2 }
=> [{:a=>"one", :b=>"two", :id=>2}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due", :id=>2}, {:a=>"en", :b=>"to", :id=>2}]
```

But the result of `arr_1`'s `id` is affected by `arr_2` each loop operation which is become `2`

```
irb(main):006:0> arr_1
=> [{:a=>"one", :b=>"two", :id=>2}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due", :id=>2}, {:a=>"en", :b=>"to", :id=>2}]
```

I have tried by using

```
arr_1 = arr
arr_2 = arr
```

but the result keeps showing the same result.
How to make the `arr_1` hashes `:id = 1` and `arr_2` hashes `:id = 2` ?

Comment: No need to prefix your title with "Ruby - " -- that's what tags are for. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging for a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see what is happening.

```
arr = [{a: "cat", b: "dog"}, {a: "uno", b: "due"}]
arr.object_id
  #=> 4557280
```

```
arr1 = arr
arr1.object_id
  #=> 4557280
```

As you see, the variables `arr` and `arr1` hold the same object, because the objects have the same object id.<sup>1</sup> Therefore, if that object is modified, `arr` and `arr1` will still both hold that object. Let's try it.

```
arr[0] = {a: "cat", b: "dog"}
arr
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>"dog"}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due"}] 
arr.object_id
  #=> 4557280
```

```
arr1
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>"dog"}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due"}] 
arr1.object_id
  #=> 4557280
```

If we want to be able to modify `arr` in this way without it affecting `arr1`, we use the method [Kernel#dup](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-dup).

```
arr
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>"dog"}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due"}] 
arr1 = arr.dup
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>"dog"}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due"}]
```

```
arr.object_id
  #=> 4557280 
arr1.object_id
  #=> 3693480
```

```
arr.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [2631980, 4557300] 
arr1.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [2631980, 4557300]
```

As you see, `arr` and `arr1` now hold different objects. Those objects, however, are arrays whose corresponding elements (hashes) are the same objects. Let's modify one of `arr`'s elements.

```
arr[1][:a] = "owl"
arr
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>"dog"}, {:a=>"owl", :b=>"due"}] 
arr.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [2631980, 4557300]
```

`arr` still contains the same objects, but we have modified one. Let's look at `arr1`.

```
arr1
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>"dog"}, {:a=>"owl", :b=>"due"}] 
arr1.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [2631980, 4557300]
```

Should we be surprised that `arr1` has changed as well?

We need to `dup` both `arr` and the elements of `arr`.

```
arr = [{a: "one", b: "two"}, {a: "uno", b: "due"}]
arr1 = arr.dup.map(&:dup)
  #=> [{:a=>"one", :b=>"two"}, {:a=>"uno", :b=>"due"}]
```

```
arr.object_id
  #=> 4149120 
arr1.object_id
  #=> 4182360
```

```
arr.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [4149200, 4149140] 
arr1.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [4182340, 4182280]
```

Now `arr` and `arr1` are different objects and they contain different (hash) objects, so any change to one will not affect the other. (Try it.)

Now suppose `arr` were as follows.

```
arr = [{a: "cat", b: [1,2]}]
```

Let's make the copy.

```
arr1 = arr.dup.map(&:dup)
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>[1, 2]}]
```

Now modify `arr[0][:b]`.

```
arr[0][:b] << 3
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>[1, 2, 3]}] 
arr1
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>[1, 2, 3]}]
```

Drat! `arr1` changed. We can again look at object ids to see why that happened.

```
arr.object_id
  #=> 4488500
arr1.object_id
  #=> 4503140
```

```
arr.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [4488520] 
arr1.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [4503100]
```

```
arr[0][:b].object_id
  #=> 4488560 
arr1[0][:b].object_id
  #=> 4488560
```

We see that `arr` and `arr1` are different objects and there respective hashes are the same elements, but the array is the same object for both hashes. We therefore need to do something like this:

```
arr1[0][:b] = arr[0][:b].dup
```

but that's still not good enough if `arr` were:

```
arr = [{a: "cat", b: [1,[2,3]]}]
```

What we need is a method that will make a *deep copy*. A common solution for that is to use the methods [Marshal::dump](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) and [Marshal::load](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Marshal.html#method-c-lump).

```
arr = [{a: "cat", b: [1,2]}]
str = Marshal.dump(arr)
  #=> "\x04\b[\x06{\a:\x06aI\"\bcat\x06:\x06ET:\x06b[\ai\x06i\a" 
arr1 = Marshal.load(str)
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>[1, 2]}]
```

```
arr[0][:b] << 3
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>[1, 2, 3]}]
arr 
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>[1, 2, 3]}]  
arr1
  #=> [{:a=>"cat", :b=>[1, 2]}]
```

Note we could write:

```
arr1 = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(arr))
```

As explained in the doc, the serialization used by the `Marshal` methods is not necessarily the same for different Ruby versions. If, for example, `dump` were used to produce a string that was saved to file and later `load` was invoked on the contents of the file, using a different version of Ruby, the contents may not be readable. Of course that's not a problem in this application of the methods.

<sup>1. To make it easier to see differences in object id's I've only shown the last seven digits. They in all cases are preceded by the digits `4877798`.</sup>

Comment: Or maybe `arr1 = arr.map { |h| h.merge(id: 1) }` and `arr2 = arr.map { |h| h.merge(id: 2) }` (assuming it fits the real context). You could also use `Marshal` to do a deep clone.

Comment: This does the shallow copy and this doesn't work if it has one more level of hash or that one more level of hash subject to the mutation